# I need to pass var information to a function using buttons

Tags: javascript, function, object, button, var

I need to pass the value to the function to update the object. There are many more buttons. this is just a shot version. The problem is that all button presses update the function with the first value found in the list "button one"

```
<div class="streams" style="width:620px;border:0px;">
<span style='color:green'>Online Streams</span>
<span style='color:grey'>Offline Streams</span>

<input type="button" id="streamName" value="Khaldor" onclick="changestream1();" >
<input type="button" id="streamName" value="Painuser" onclick="changestream1();" >

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changestream1() 
    {
        var streamInput = document.getElementById('streamName').value;
        var object = document.getElementById('live_embed_player_flash');
        var param = document.getElementById('param');
        object.setAttribute("data", "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + streamInput);
        param.setAttribute("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=" + streamInput + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25");
    }
</script>

<div id="streamHolder">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" bgcolor="#000000">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
        <param id="param" name="flashvars" />
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: thats how i set the var streamName. is there another method other than 
    document.getElementByID('streamName').value;
that i can use to assign the var streamInput?

Comment: See my answer, you CANNOT use the same ID more than once, the accepted way to group similar elements is to use a common *class*

Comment: can someone show me how i could implement

$(".streams").click(function() {

Comment: If you decide to go with `jquery` and use the above code: `$(".streams").click(function() { ` -- inside of that function, `($this)` represents the current element being clicked as a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's **must** be unique, but you could save some time and add a parameter to your function that takes the current element being clicked:

```
onclick="changestream1(this);"

function changestream1(obj) 
{
    var streamInput = obj.value;
    var object = document.getElementById('live_embed_player_flash');
    var param = document.getElementById('param');
    object.setAttribute("data", "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + streamInput);
    param.setAttribute("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=" + streamInput + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25");
}
```

Comment: does this look right?

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changestream1(obj) 
 {
        var streamInput = console.log(obj.value);

Comment: @user3602130 -- No - i've edited my answer - the `console.log` was merely there to show the value in the console, it has no actual impact on the logic

Comment: I have a lot more coding to do. is it ok if i email you if I have another problem? I will try my best to figure it out for myself first.

Comment: Just post another question on this site when you get stuck. Plenty more people here who love to help

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 buttons have the id `streamName`. Try with different IDs.

Edit

`var streamInput = this.value;`

Comment: can you show me how i could implement

$(".streams").click(function() {

Comment: Try this : `var streamInput = this.value;`

Answer (score 0):

These elements

```
<input type="button" id="streamName" value="Khaldor" onclick="changestream1();" >
<input type="button" id="streamName" value="Painuser" onclick="changestream1();" >
```

both have the same `id`, so Javascript is grabbing the first one since it's ambiguous which button reall is `streamName`. Make the `id` unique for each.